# Angular7 - Inject Component in another Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-components

Is it correct inject Component in another Component to access functions or properties in injected Component?

**Notice: None of these components is a child of another**

```
import { UsersComponent } from './../users/users.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(users:UsersComponent){
    users.getAllUsers()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't actually do it this way. In Angular, we think everything as a component wise. If any method or property is used by multiple component you can follow below methods. As your components are not related as child parent. you can follow 3 and 4 Methods.

**1. Parent to Child and Child to Parent:** Sharing Data via @Input and @Output

This is most frequently used way of sharing data between components. It uses @Input() decorator. You can also use @Output() decorator to event pass to the parent.

parent.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <app-child [input]="parentData" (output)="childMsg($event)"></app-child>`
})
export class ParentComponent{
  message: string;
  parentData = "message from parent"
  childMsg(event) {
    this.message = event;
  }
}
```

child.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <p>{{ input }}</p>
    <button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() input: string;
  @Output() output = new EventEmitter<string>();
  message: string = "Hello World!"
  submit() {
    this.output.emit(this.message)
  }
}
```

**2. Child to Parent:** Sharing Data via ViewChild

@ViewChild decorator allows a one component to be injected into another, giving the parent access to its properties and methods.

parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    Message: {{ childData }}
    <app-child></app-child>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child;    

  childData: string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.childData = this.child.message
  }
}
```

child.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
})
export class ChildComponent {

  childData = 'Hola Mundo!';

}
```

N.B: we use AfterViewInit lifeCycle because the child wasn't available until the view is initialized.

**3. Unrelated Components using Service:** Sharing Data between unrelated components with a Service and Behavior Subject

common.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
  private data = new BehaviorSubject('default data');
  data$ = this.data.asObservable();

  changeData(data: string) {
    this.data.next(data)
  }
}
```

component-one.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-one',
  template: `<p>{{data}}</p>`
})
export class ComponentOneComponent implements OnInit {

  data: string;

  constructor(private service: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.data$.subscribe(res => this.data = res)
  }

}
```

component-two.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-two',
  template: `
    <p>{{data}}</p>
    <button (click)="newData()">Next Data</button>`
})
export class ComponentTwoComponent implements OnInit {

  data: string;

  constructor(private service: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.data$.subscribe(res => this.data = res)
  }
  newData() {
    this.service.data.next('Changed Data');
  }
}
```

**4. State Management:** Share data between unrelated components using NgRx
You can use store like NgRx to manage state where you will store your property then use everywhere. [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f97ICOaekNU&t=2s) I followed this example when learning ngrx.

Comment: In last example (component-two.component.ts) I think you mean:
`export class ComponentTwoComponent`

Comment: yes you are right, I just copy the componentOne and tried to edit and forgot to edit the class name.

Comment: Thank you for  typical answer so helpful to me.

Comment: you can inject a component in another component like a service, and access the public variable or function. Try it

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot inject 1 component in to another. You should create a service for that.

You can use  [**Behaviour Subject**](https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc) to communicate between 2 unrelated components.

See this [tutorial](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/simplest-way-to-share-data-between-two-unrelated-components-in-angular)

Comment: yes I know about  Behaviour Subject, but I want to know is it a problem if I inject component in another one?