# Correct way to pass data from parent to grandchild in Angular. Is that correct?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass data from parent component to a child component. I have somthing like that:

Parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo-parent',
  templateUrl: './foo-parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo-parent.component.scss'],
})
export class FooParent {

  @Input() data: any;

  constructor() { }

}
```

The parent receives the data from another library where all the logic is executed.

Grandchild component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo-grand-child',
  templateUrl: './foo-grand-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo-grand-child.component.sass'],
})

export class FooGrandChild {

  data: any;

  constructor(private fooParent: FooParent) {
    this.data = this.fooParent.fooGrandChildData;
   }
```

This way works correctly but I'm a newbie and I don't know if it's the right way to do it. Is there another way to do it other than bridging the parent > child > grandchild component?

Comment: Another not necessarily better way is to inject angular service

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that is the `Angular` way to communicate data between your components. As you already know the relationship between your components *(which is good)*, You can pick the right method of communication between your components.

I suggest reading
**https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/**

As for your use case. *Parent to Grand Children*.

I suggest using a `Service`, that's set the `field/property` by your `Parent Component` and then your `Grandchild Component` gets that `field/property`, instead of directly `Injecting` the `Parent Component` in your `Grandchild Component`

### Parent Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo-parent',
  templateUrl: './foo-parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo-parent.component.scss'],
})
export class FooParent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sharedtestService: SharedTestService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.sharedtestService.setTestData('string');
  }    
}
```

### Grandchild Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo-grand-child',
  templateUrl: './foo-grand-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo-grand-child.component.sass'],
})

export class FooGrandChild implements OnInit {

  data: string;

  constructor(private sharedtestService: SharedTestService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.data = this.sharedtestService.getTestData();
  }
 }
```

### Shared Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedTestService {
  testData: string;
  constructor() {}

  setTestData(temp: string): void {
    return this.testData = temp;
  }

  getTestData(): string {
    return this.testData;
  }
}
```

I also suggest looking into `Observables`and how to subscribe to them, if you want your `GrandChildren Component` to automatically listen to changes that are done by your `Parent Component`.

Comment: Thx for the info!

Comment: Love that explanation from the web that you said!

Comment: Welcome, there is also a 5th method through which you can send data, i.e. `State Management`, but it's an overkill for small applications. But just for learning purposes read the selected answer in the link I shared below, it contains the same point plus an additional one which is `State Management`. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840048/angular7-inject-component-in-another-component

Comment: Shared services are global state. This means you can have lingering state or multiple components updating the same global state (race conditions).

Comment: Thank you for the provided Fireship.io link and this great example!

Answer (score 1):

Several things, first of all if you want to pass something from a parent to a child and from this to its child (the grandchild of the parent component) in the children (where you receive the data) we use the @Input() decorator not in the parent. @Input() data is in @output() data is out.
This is why @Input() should be used on child components.
Once you have the @Input in the child component you can pass the value to that variable through the HTML. I show you an example:

Child (ts):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-sample-component',
    templateUrl: './child-sample-component.component.html',
})

export class ChildSampleComponenet {
    @Input() childObject;
}
```

Parent (html):

```
 <child-sample-component [childObject]="parentObject">

 </child-sample-component>
```

Notice how in the child we have the @Input with the childObject variable and in the parent html we give the value to childObject with the parentObject parent variable that will contain whatever.

There are other ways as well such as using services etc. But you should learn that as you go. Here are a couple of interesting links.

https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: I know how it works and i told that the ```@Input``` in the parent component comes from another component that do all the logic

Comment: Angular is opinionated. Data flows from parent to children. Events with data flow from children to parent. This prevents event loops and responsibilities in the parent that really should be in the child.